# Usage of predicate function in std::remove_if

Tags: c++

I have a vector of objects. My data structure is the following:

```
 class my_class{
       float a; int b;
 };
 my_class obj;
 vector<my_class> vec;
```

The vector vec contains data of the form:

```
 vec
 ((10.0,2),(100,3),(19.0,3)...)
```

Now from vector vec I intend to delete the elements which are less than or equal to the last element of vec...For this I am using erase and remove_if functions:

```
vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), predicate_function(vec, (vec.end()-1).a, (vec.end()-1).b)), vec.end());
```

The predicate_function which I have does an iteration over "vec". However, this defeats the purpose of using std::remove_if. Can someone please help as to what the predicate_function should look like in order for remove_if to work. I dont want to use lambda_function. Also my compiler is GCC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The predicate function will automatically be passed the parameters from each Iterator. So it'd look something like:

```
bool predicate_function(const my_class& m)
{
    //Some logic here
}
```

Which would then simply be called as:

```
vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), predicate_function), vec.end());
```

In C++ terms, `std::remove_if` expects a `UnaryPredicate` as its 3rd parameter, which is either a function or functor accepting 1 argument and returning `bool`.

Edit: To do what you want in the comment, you'd need to use a `functor` (or `std::bind`, but we'll go the functor route here):

```
struct compare_last
{
    const my_class last_;

    compare_last(const my_class& last)
      : last_(last)
    { }

    bool operator()(const my_class& m) const
    {
        return m == last_; //Or however you do your comparisons
    }
};

my_class& last = *(--vec.end());
vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), compare_last(last)), vec.end());
```

Comment: Now inside the predicate_function how would I perform comparison with the last object of the vector...since the predicate object is passed parameters of just one iterator. PS: Thanks for replying

Comment: Don't you think the `remove_if()` removes what needs to be removed? Why did you keep the `vec.erase()`? Not only that, but vec.end() may change between the time you call it as the last parameter of the `erase()` and the time `remove_if()` returns.

Comment: @AlexisWilke [No, it doesn't](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove). This is a well-known C++ idiom: the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom). The only way `vec.end()` could actually change is if this was in accessed without synchronization in a multithreaded environment.